Apache mod_rewrite - allow access to directory/
Apache 2.4   mod_rewrite  .htaccess   located in somedir
I want to deny access to everything in a directory except index.html and 403.html
Below works.
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "index.html" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "403.html" [NC]
RewriteRule "^.*$" "-" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^.*$" [NC,OR]
RewriteRule "^.*$" "403.html" [L]

BUT http://.../somedir and  http://.../somedir/ are denied, and I want them to act the same as specifying "index.html"
I tried a few things which did not work, or gave surprising results
DirectoryIndexRedirect on  # NO HELP

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "" [OR]   # allows everything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^.*$" [OR]  # allows everything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ="" [OR]  # denies everything

[ gnashing of teeth ] ensues

First step: clean up your implementation: remove all the quote characters, they are not required. Remove the NC flags, not required as well here. Remove that last OR flag in the last RewriteCond, it breaks the interpretation of the condition, replace the matching pattern "^.*$" in both rules with just ^, which does exactly the same.

Thanks.  Cleaned up.  But still the same problem.

Sure, as said that does not change the behavior, it just makes things easier to tackle if you keep out unnecessary things. Please also update the question accordingly.
